# Dynamically change lambda sort function in Python

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

In Python I have a list of objects, and I can sort them by attributes `a` or `b` using

```
obj_list = sorted(obj_list, key=lambda x:x.a)
```

or

```
obj_list = sorted(obj_list, key=lambda x:x.b)
```

The sort selected (`a` or `b` or many other options) depends on user input, so I'd like to be able to have a single sorting statement and pass it the sort key – something like this:

```
def sortfunc(attribute):
    return lambda x:attribute
```

I know that won't work, but is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can just not use lambda and go for a normal function that does the check.

Comment: `lambda x: getattr(x, attribute)`…